# Problem in Highlighiting the active page in appbar

Tags: css, reactjs, react-router, material-ui

I'm trying to give the highlighting to the active page in my navbar with a background color of white and the color of the text as skyblue. But for some reason I'm not able to see the color of the text skyblue applied in the appbar. You can see how it is displaying in the picture attached below.

```
                    <Box>
                        <IconButton>
                            <NavLink to='/' 
                             activeClassName='selected'>
                                <Typography
                                    variant='body1'
                                    style={{
                                        marginRight: "1rem",
                                        color: "white",
                                    }}>
                                    Dashboard
                                </Typography>
                            </NavLink>
                            <NavLink
                                to='/aboutus'
                                activeClassName='selected'>
                                <Typography
                                    variant='body1'
                                    style={{
                                        marginRight: "1rem",
                                        color: "white",
                                    }}>
                                    About Us
                                </Typography>
                            </NavLink>
                            <NavLink
                                to='/contactus'
                                activeClassName='selected'>
                                <Typography
                                    variant='body1'
                                    style={{
                                        marginRight: "1rem",
                                        color: "white",
                                    }}>
                                    Contact Us
                                </Typography>
                            </NavLink>
                        </IconButton>
                    </Box>
```

The Styles used for this are here:

```
    .selected {
        background-color: white;
        color: skyblue;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: I imagine the inline `color: "white"` is resulting in an inline style that has higher priority than your class based style.

Comment: Because you have the color style added in Typography. Your active class is getting applied but you're specifically passing the color to the typography, hence it is taking that color based on priority.

Answer (score 1):

Because you have the color style added in Typography. Your active class is getting applied but you're specifically passing the color to the typography, hence it is taking that color based on priority.

You can possibly do something like this.

```css
.nav-link {
  margin-right: "1rem"; 
  color: "white";
}
.selected {
  background-color: white;
  color: skyblue;
}
```

```html
<Box>
  <IconButton>
    <NavLink to='/' activeClassName='selected' className="nav-link">
      <Typography variant='body1'>
        Dashboard
      </Typography>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink to='/aboutus' className="nav-link" activeClassName='selected'>
      <Typography variant='body1'>
        About Us
      </Typography>
    </NavLink>
    <NavLink to='/contactus' className="nav-link" activeClassName='selected'>
      <Typography variant='body1'>
        Contact Us
      </Typography>
    </NavLink>
  </IconButton>
</Box>
```

If this doesn't work you can add this as a class and conditionally toggle it with the active state.

EDIT: Thanks @DBS for pointing out the mistake in the earlier answer.

Comment: An inline style will still override the class style, you would need to either apply a new style inline, or apply all styles using classes to easily work around this.

Comment: Though we are applying the external styles we are not getting the desired output. The color for the inactive pages is not white but they are appearing as the regular links

Comment: Can you share the expected result and current results? Also if possible share the working example.

Comment: Figured out the issue in the CSS margin-right: "1rem";   color: "white"; We need to take the "" out I'm trying it with them so that's the reason why I'm not getting the desired output.